# Updating a JavaFX property with the same value

Tags: java, javafx, properties

I would like to give a DoubleProperty the same value again. Alternatively a simple update would be nice. Unfortunately i haven't found a possibility yet, if this is possible at all.

The following code example illustrates my intentions:

```
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoubleProperty p = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        p.addListener((obs_p, old_p, new_p) -> {
            System.out.println("Here, the value: " + new_p);
        });
    
        p.set(1);
        p.set(1);
    }
}
```

or a solution that looks something like this:

```
p.update() ...
```

Overall I would like to receive the following output:

```
Here, the value: 1.0
Here, the value: 1.0
```

But only one line is output.
Do such methods even exist?

Comment: why? that's against the design principle of observable values/properties: they intentionally restrict notifications to _actual changes_ (in your case nothing is changed, so no reason to fire anything)

Comment: Thank you for the legitimate question. Well, there are situations in my application that some objects are not instanced (resp. they are "null"). Here it would be helpful if the addlistener could be called again with the existing value for a simple refresh.

Comment: sounds like something wrong in your setup, best to change it - it's always wrong to work against the design of a framework

Comment: If the value doesn't change, then what exactly are you refreshing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend SimpleDoubleProperty and override the set(double);

```
public class CustomDoubleProperty extends SimpleDoubleProperty {

    @Override
    public void set(double d) {
        super.set(d);
        System.out.println("set value: " + d);
    }
}
```

Comment: this will not catch changes from bindings .. though given the incorrect usage by the OP, that might not matter ;)

Comment: Yeah. I was assuming he just wanted a quick change request notification "hack".